# Convert list elements to list values of another list

Tags: python-3.x, list, set

I am trying to convert list elements of a given list to list value of another list. Here is an example:

```
list1 = ['apple', 'tomato', 'milk', 'beans', 'mango']
list2 = [{0,4}, {1,3}, 2]
result = []
```

expected output:

```
[{'apple', 'banana'}, {'tomato', 'beans'}, 'milk']
```

I am trying to use the below code, but it does not work:

```
for i in list2:
    result.append(list1[i])
```

Comment: What have you attempted to deal with set elements, and what issues do you have with the implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `list2` will only contain `set`, `list`, or `int`. This would be my approach.

```
list1 = ['apple', 'tomato', 'milk', 'beans', 'mango']
list2 = [{0,4}, {1,3}, 2]
result = []

# [{'apple', 'banana'}, {'tomato', 'beans'}, 'milk']

for x in list2:
    temp_lst = []
    if type(x) in [set, list]:
        new_set = set()
        for y in x:
            new_set.add(list1[y])
        temp_lst.append(new_set)
        

    else:
        temp_lst.append(list1[x])
    
    result.extend(temp_lst)

print(result)
```